# Share VPN connection via one PC (Without WiFi)

Tags: windows, vpn, sharing

Right, I know that there are plenty of similar questions already, but none seem to answer my particular question, so here it goes...

I have a subscription with ExpressVPN, for which I have their client software on one of my desktop windows 10 based PC, what I would like to achieve is  to "force" all other devices to connect to the Internet via that PC, but I don't want to set that PC up as a router, at the moment I have a modem/router that does that job, and manages the WiFi hotpots (2.4 & 5) etcetera...

Is there a way to tell the other devices to connect to that PC, using its static LAN IP address, and then connect out to the Internet via the VPN tunnel?

Basically turning it into some sort of gateway to the Internet, I don't want to use the WiFi hot-spot option, as I would like the wired devices to do the same, is there a way to forward all my LAN devices internet requests through that PC?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe setting up a proxy server on the PC will do what I want to do... But I am still investigating... any help is welcome

Comment: If the proxy server is the solution, which I haven't tested yet, a second problem has come up, how do I force all LAN devices to go through the proxy at router level, without having to set the proxy on each device?

Comment: If you have an ethernet LAN in your network, connect modem and router with your residential vpn server and connected to the vpn in that. Setup ics there and connect the rest computer to that using a switch.

Answer (score 0):

What you are essentially trying to do is create a one-armed router (a.k.a. a router on stick).

The biggest issue you face is establishing the VPN connection and sharing it. There are a lot of bugs with using Internet Connection Sharing in latest builds of Win10 so that may or may not work for you.  As long as you can establish the VPN connection and the PC is acting as the proxy and tunnel, you just set your DHCP server (which is most likely your modem/router that connects to your ISP)  to *issue the IP address of the proxy/PC as the gateway address* to all your LAN clients. As long as each LAN client (WiFi connected or not) is receiving the Gateway of the PC/Proxy Server, they will route all traffic through that and, subsequently, through the VPN.

So for example - your router/modem that runs your internet connection is on 192.168.1.1 and your PC/Proxy Server is on 192.168.1.254.  You then tell your LAN clients (via the DHCP server) to use 192.168.1.254 as the gateway (and probably as the DNS) and traffic will route through that device instead of your main internet connection.

You probably want to set all the clients to get the proxy server as the DNS server or use a public DNS like cloudflare or google. Otherwise you might have DNS leaks through your main internet connection.

I use a raspberry pi as a one armed router that is on 24/7 and I send certain devices on my network through it using this method.